# Runge-Kutta identity for $y'=\lambda y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

An $r$-stage (explicit) RK method of order $r$, step size $h$, is applied to the scalar equation $y'=\lambda y$. Show that
$$y_{n+1}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^r\frac{1}{i!}(h\lambda)^i\right)y_n.$$
I have tried to write the method explicitly, as
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+h\sum_{i=1}^r b_ik_i,$$
where $k_1=\lambda y_n$, $k_2=\lambda y_n+\lambda^2 hc_2y_n$ etc, but it's all getting rather messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think more simply. Take the given data at face value. The exact solution with $y(0)=y_0$ is $y(t)=y_0e^{λt}$. Being of **global order** $r$ means for the step of size $h$ that
$$
y_1=y_0+h\Phi_f(0,y_0,h)=y(h)+O(h^{r+1})
$$
So now what is $e^{λh}$ truncated at the order $O(h^{r+1})$?

Then use that with $r$ **stages** you can also not get a higher polynomial degree.